# onlyoffice set default font

Tags: font-size, font-family, onlyoffice

When the file is empty, the default font style is Arial, and the font size is 11.
I want to change the default font size to 16
Where can I modify the source code?
[image]

I expect that when the file is empty, the default font size and font style can be configured by myself, rather than the Arial provided by onlyOffice.

Answer (score 0):

When you integrate Document Server with your own application, the Document Server doesn't create files in this sceanario itself, it merely uses the ones you specify. Specifically, you pass this url https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/config/document#url in the editor configuration with the desired file to be opened for editing.  Thus, you need to set the corresponding settings in this file prior to opening it with Document Server. In this case, it will be opened for editing with the required font and style.